# easy way to save a LinkedList in a Android Application?

Tags: android

what is the easyest or native way to save a list of objects in a android application?

i need to save it and then load it when the app starts again.

would be nice maybe someone have a ready to use library which makes everything for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your items stored in the `LinkedList` implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) so you can put them in your `bundle`. The in `onSaveInstance` you can put your objects in the `bundle` using:

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList ("key", list);
```

and in `onRestoreInstanceState` of your `Activity` get the data back from that `bundle` using :

```
bundle.getParcelableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't provide full answers, but since it's in my clipboard...

This should work with any List implementation.

Further you'll need to to define / exchange `Constants.EXTERNAL_CACHE_DIR` and might want to use something else than the UI-Thread for production.

```
 public static void persistList(final List<String> listToPersist, final String fileName) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    File outFile = new File(Constants.EXTERNAL_CACHE_DIR, fileName);
    try {
      if (outFile.createNewFile()) {
        writer = new FileWriter(outFile);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        for (String item : listToPersist) {
          bufferedWriter.write(item + "\n");
        }
        bufferedWriter.close();
        writer.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Exception while writing to file", ioe);
    }
  }

  public static List<String> readList(final String fileName) {
    List<String> readList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File(Constants.EXTERNAL_CACHE_DIR, fileName));
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
      String current = null;
      while ((current = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        readList.add(current);
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Didn't find file", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Error while reading file", e);
    }
    return readList;
  }
```

Comment: why would you use a file to persist an simple array? it can be stored more easily in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Because Parcelable is pretty verbose and has to be implemented for each and every class that you want to persist.

Comment: Yes. But it easy more easy to keep objects. In this case, you are persisting Strings. How would you go with this approach, and persist more complex objects?

Comment: I mainly make them Parcelable. But using ProtoBuf for that also has a great performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried shared preferneces..? when ur app is about to exit, save that using shared preferences and again when app starts, load that preference.

Comment: i think shared preference used for small data he has entire linked list

Comment: what you mean by less data? You can save any object in shared preference.