# Simple way to store a Linked List

Tags: android, linked-list, persistence

Hi I am currently working on an Android application, and I need to store a LinkedList when the user terminated the app from the app processes. I have looked at this question [easy way to save a LinkedList in a Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818922/easy-way-to-save-a-linkedlist-in-a-android-application)

And the accepted answer doesn't seem to work and AndroidStudio complains that it expects and Array List rather than a Linked List. I realise this question is 3 years old and something must have changed in that time for it not to work.

Can Linked lists be stored in a Bundle anymore? Or does anyone have a better way of making my LinkedList Persistant?

Cheers

Comment: I don't think the question/answer you linked ever supported `LinkedList`, as it uses a method called `putParcelableArrayList`, which expects an `ArrayList`, and always has. Probably, the user who asked the question changed their list from a `LinkedList` to an `ArrayList` as that seems to be the best solution, unless you have some specific reason for using `LinkedList` over `ArrayList`

Comment: Im using the LinkedList as a Queue for sending messages out so its quite important at least in that respect. I want to save the list in a bundle during the onSaveInstanceState so that i can call them back up when the application is reopened by the user and instantiate the new queues with the persistant data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you won't be able to save a `LinkedList` to a bundle, but you can, however, convert your `LinkedList` to an `ArrayList` to save it, then convert it back when you load it into your application again. The constructor for `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` accept a `Collection` and will add the elements in the order that their iterator returns them (i.e. FIFO for your LinkedList)

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ArrayList<MyObject> listToSave = new ArrayList<MyObject>(myLinkedList);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", listToSave);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ArrayList<MyObject> loadedList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
        myLinkedList = new LinkedList<MyObject>(loadedList);
    }
}
```