# pass linkedlist in intent

Tags: android, android-intent, linked-list

i am trying to pass linked-list with component button in intent by clicking of button pass intent from first activity  to second activity and show it
 in textview in second activity but
code below is not working properly

> firstActivity.java

```
            package com.example.intentsdemo;

                 import java.io.Serializable;
               import java.util.LinkedList;
        import java.util.List;

            import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
     import android.view.Menu;
          import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
List<Button> array=new LinkedList<Button>();
EditText txt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:123456"));
            //startActivity(intent);
        boolean  msg=   array.add(btn);
        //  String msg = btn.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("data",(Serializable) array);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
        }
    });
    }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

> secondActivity.java

```
    package com.example.intentsdemo;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
       import android.view.Menu;
       import android.widget.TextView;

       public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    Serializable x = b.getSerializable("data");
    //txt.sett

TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tt.setText("bundle "+x);

    /*Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    b.putString("newMsg",x);

    i.putExtras(b);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);

    finish();*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_second, menu);
    return true;
}

     }
```

Help Will be appreciated!!!!

Comment: You just can't pass ui elements via intent

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your LinkedList in a Java object which implements `Parceleable`:

[easy way to save a LinkedList in a Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818922/easy-way-to-save-a-linkedlist-in-a-android-application)